# I can't activate Wifi or Bluetooth on a Toshiba Satellite Laptop

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I'm new to Ubuntu and i installed Ubuntu 13.10 to my Toshiba Satellite L500D laptop. But wifi and Bluetooth are not working, although wireless connectivity light is always on. How can I activate  wifi and connect with a device over Bluetooth. Please be so kind and give me an easy to follow answer. On the connectivity tab it says,that  wifi is disabled by the hardware switch.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, after 3 days of searching and delusion yesterday night, 17 of July, my Asus EeePC 1015PX ,was blessed with a new update kernel, and wifi was solved ... so if you are having problems connecting, update Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For wifi, you will have to connect via cable and see if there is any proprietary driver for your adapter. Go to software center and Edit - Software channels (sources), then go to the last tab "Additonal Drivers".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bsh
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

That should solve your problem.